# INFORMIX - Pivot Table

Tags: crystal-reports, informix

I have a problem with informix database,

I have a log table, like this

```
name     datetime     event
 A        08:00         1
 B        03:00         2
 A        04:00         3
 C        05:00         4
 V        06:00         1
 A        11:00         7
 etc

NOTE : 1 => LOGIN
       7 => LOGOUT
```

I want generate a report, like this

```
name    login     logout
 A      08:00     11:00
 A      11:09     12:00
 etc
```

I need a query to solved My problem.

Answer (score 0):

First Group by **name**

1. create text feilds **Login** and **Logout** and place those in group header.

Now in detail add below formulas for login and logout.

login

```
if event=1
then datetime
```

Place in detail fo login

logout

```
if event=7
then datetime
```

Place in detail of logout

supress group footer

Comment: I want generate a query for that output, what kind of query can solved that

Comment: Just follow the steps in crystal report and then go to **Database tab---> Show SQL query** you get the query

Answer (score 0):

have a look below link.

[Dynamic PIVOT using C# Linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12866685/dynamic-pivot-using-c-sharp-linq)

use parameter as you want to pivot the data.