# How to get the data of specific user in one row

Tags: c#, sql, database, linq, informix

If I have table with a structure like that :

```
serial    regnum    value    type

  1         55      100     normal

  2         55      66      Light

  3         77      70      normal

  4         30      40      Light
```

---

Now if i want to get the data concerning the `regnum = 55`  in one record not two with the following structure :

```
regnum  normal   light

 55       100      66
```

How to do this through sql query or through LINQ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have to use a pivot logic. Here is an example, where a DataTable is pivoted to convert row values into columns.

[Dynamic PIVOT using C# Linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12866685/dynamic-pivot-using-c-sharp-linq/21133216#21133216)

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(c.type) 
            FROM table_name c
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT regnum, ' + @cols + ' from 
            (
                select regnum
                    , value
                    , type
                from table_name
           ) x
            pivot 
            (
                 sum(value)
                for type in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '


execute(@query)
```

Answer (score 1):

select * from TABLE_NAME pivot (sum(value) for type in (Light,normal))
AS PVTTable
where regnum=55

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT regnum, SUM(ISNULL(Light,0)) AS Light, SUM(ISNULL(normal,0)) AS Normal     
FROM 
    temp_sc  
  PIVOT (sum(value) FOR Type IN (Light,normal)) AS PVTTable
WHERE regnum=55
GROUP BY regnum
```

Answer (score -1):

```
mysql query = "SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE regnum = 55"
```

above will get all data with regnum = 55.

to be more specific:

```
mysql query = "SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE regnum =55 AND type="Light" "
```

to get regnum 55 with type light